Renault clio 3 2006 model not starting
My Renault clio 3 2006 model, is not even cranking but displays the dash lights and everything else is working perfectly fine, wipers, light, horn etc.
In addition, I left the car for 5 months. I came back to change the fuel pump since the older one was acting up. When I came back I didn't check if the car was still starting before I changed the fuel pump, but now it is not starting anymore.
I have tried turning the starter manually and it's perfectly fine.
I have also checked the fuses and they are fine as well.
What may be the problem?

This post needs clarification. 1) did you remove the starter to check it manually or jumpered two terminals on the starter to get it run and turn over the engine? 2) is this a no start, dead silence failure of engine startup or the starter turns the engine over but the engine never fires up?
